# Sprint Boot Mongo Respositry Hangs on Second Reqeust

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I'm running into a strange issue using SpringBoot MongoRepository.

I've localized the problem to returning the response to the request after it has successfully queried my Mongo instance. I have a simple object that I am querying. On start I can query and get back a response instantly. After that it just hangs after it has successfully queried Mongo.

This is the extent of the logs when the issue happens

```
2021-04-13 21:20:03 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [MongoQueryCreator.java:160] Created query Query: { "trackingCode" : "PERS4J"}, Fields: {}, Sort: {}
2021-04-13 21:20:03 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [MongoTemplate.java:2551] find using query: { "trackingCode" : "PERS4J"} fields: Document{{}} for class: class com.gotem.domain.Link in collection: link
2021-04-13 21:20:03 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [SLF4JLogger.java:56] Sending command '{"find": "link", "filter": {"trackingCode": "PERS4J"}, "limit": 2, "$db": "gotem"}' with request id 9 to database gotem on connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:11}] to server localhost:27017
2021-04-13 21:20:03 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [SLF4JLogger.java:56] Execution of command with request id 9 completed successfully in 2.47 ms on connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:11}] to server localhost:27017
```

This is using Spring Boot 2.2.0.RELEASE against Mongo 4.4.3.

I'm stumped :/

Adding simplified setup and config.

**application.properties**

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017/linkTrack
```

**Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface LinkRepository extends MongoRepository<Link, Long> {
    Link findOneByTrackingCode(String trackingCode); 
}
```

**Query Controller**

```
public class LinkController {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LinkController.class);
    @Autowired
    private LinkRepository linkRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/retrieve/{trackingCode}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Link findOneByTrackingCode(@PathVariable String trackingCode) {
        Link link = linkRepository.findOneByTrackingCode(trackingCode);
        LOG.debug("Link: " + link);
        return link;
    }
}
```

**Object**

```
@Document
public class Link implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String trackingCode;
    
    public Link() {
        this.trackingCode = "123456"; // THIS WAS THE ISSUE :(
    }

    private getTrackingCode(){
        return this.trackingCode
    };
  
}
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly by hangs? Is is blocked forever? How are you already triggering the db query? Could you add all the relevant code and configuration snippets?

Comment: I see the execution above and then it never does anything else. The next line after the repository find is a debug line to output the object. The first request after start up will return it, after it stops there. Adding the config details above.

Comment: I see the repository definition `LinkRepository extends MongoRepository<Link, Long>`, needs to be `LinkRepository extends MongoRepository<Link, String>`. Also, try using the `@Query` annotation with your find method to specify that you are passing a parameter to the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. Crap. I had a constructor in the Link Object that added a generated id to the trackingCode field and once removed it worked as expected.

I still am at a loss as to why it worked on the first request after restarting the service and only hung after.